# Unit testing void methods - Jasmine, javascript

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, titanium-alloy

This is my function in the controller code that I have exposed.

```
//unit test code
    $.getMessagesUnit = function(chatId) {

        if (!(Titanium.Network.networkType === Titanium.Network.NETWORK_NONE)) {

            apiHelper.APIGetRequest(xxxxxxxx + '/messages/' + args.chatId, function(e) {
                $.view_indicator.visible = true;
                var status = this.status;
                if (status == 200) {

                    console.log('get chats');

                    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    console.log(data);

                    var rows = [];
                    var i = 0;
                    var blob;

                    for (x in data.messages) {
                        //Ti.API.debug(JSON.stringify(messages[x]));

                        var nickname = null;
                        var chatBlob = null;
                        var picture = null;
                        var timeStampCon = null;

                        chatBlob = data.messages[x].message;
                        nickname = data.messages[x].user.nickname;
                        picture = data.messages[x].user.pictures[0];

                        //alert(data.messages[x].message);

                        timeStampCon = utilities.getCurrentTimeFromStamp(data.messages[x].timestamp);
                        textArea.addLabel(timeStampCon);

                        //alert(data.messages[x].user.id);

                        if (args.pickedId == data.messages[x].user.id) {

                            textArea.recieveMessage(chatBlob);
                            textArea.addLabel("\n");

                        } else {

                            textArea.sendMessage(chatBlob);
                            textArea.addLabel("\n");

                        }

                    }

                    //return rows;
                    //end
                    $.view_indicator.visible = false;

                }


            }, function(err) {

                alert('Unknown error from api');
                $.view_indicator.visible = false;
            });

        } else {
            alert('No internet connection found');
            $.view_indicator.visible = false;
        }

    };

    //end
```

Here is my unit test code:

```
it('test chat window function.', function() {
    $ = Alloy.createController('chatWindow', {});
    expect($.getMessagesUnit(123).chatBlob). toBeDefined();
});
```

I want to test if the variables in the JSON request are defined, after the api call is made:

```
var nickname = null;
var chatBlob = null;
var picture = null;
var timeStampCon = null;
```

to ensure that the data I am getting back from the unit test is defined. I am getting the following error:

```
[INFO] :   .  ============================================================
[ERROR] :  .  THERE WERE FAILURES!
[ERROR] :  .  ============================================================
[ERROR] :  .  Recap of failing specs:
[ERROR] :  .  ------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] :  .  chatWindow controller test chat window function.. - Expected undefined to be defined.
```

I am quite new to unit testing, how can I test individual variables in a void method like that?

Cheers guys

Update - using spies:

```
it('test spies in receive message function.', function() {
    $ = Alloy.createController('chatWindow', {});
    spyOn($, 'textarea.recieveMessage');
    $.getMessagesUnit(123);
    expect(textarea.recieveMessage).toHaveBeenCalled();
});

[INFO] :   .   - test spies in receive message function.. (FAILED)
[INFO] :   .   - - Expected spy recieveMessage to have been called.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get access to the chatBlob as its only accessible inside the closure created by your success function. What you could do is add a spy to the `recieveMessage` function on your `textArea` object before you make a call to `$.getMessagesUnit(123)` then you check the spy for received calls and the args past to that call i.e. your chatBlob value.

Comment: How can I do this, cheers. I am very new at jasmine, and it driving me nuts!

Comment: amended OP with code for spies, couldn't get it to work. Cheers

Comment: The second parameter in the spyOn function needs to be name of the function you are spying on so `spyOn($.textArea, 'recieveMessage');` is what you want (Assuming the textArea is a property of the $ object.

Comment: Didn't work, it seems as though it doesn't trace into the async method. If I call that function outside of the async method it works.